# How to disable PAYMENT METHOD (CCAVENUEPAY) pragmatically when grand total is 0

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

How to disable PAYMENT METHOD (CCAVENUEPAY) pragmatically when the grand total is 0

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
    <section id="payment">
        <group id="ccavenuepay" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Ccavenuepay</label>
                <comment><![CDATA[<fieldset class="form-wrapper" id="edit-ccavenue-main-panel"">
                            <div class="fieldset-wrapper">
                                <div id="ccavenue-main-panel-left">
                                    <a href="https://www.bluezeal.in" target="_blank">
                                        <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="https://api.bluezeal.in/cca/images/logo.png" alt="Bluezeal Logo">
                                    </a><br><br> 
                                    <div>
                                        <b> <font color="sky blue">We Make </font> 
                                            <font color="red">Module</font>
                                            <font color="sky blue"> Simpler </font>
                                        </b>
                                        <span id="ccavenue_module_lic_key"></span>
                                        <span id="ccavenue_module_ver"></span>
                                        <span id="ccavenue_module_name"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div id="ccavenue-main-panel-midd">
                                    <h3 class="panel-title">CCAvenue MCPG </h3>
                                    <br> 
                                    <a style="text-decoration: none; font-size:16px;font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#09F;">Module Version:</a>
                                    <a id="module_version" style="text-decoration: none;color:#390; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold"></a>               
                                    <br>
                                    <a id ="pdf_link" style="text-decoration: none;" href="" target="_blank" style="color:#F00; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:10px;"> PDF Manual Guide</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
                                    <a id ="video_link" style="text-decoration: none;" href="" style="color:#F00; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:10px;" target="_blank">Video Tutorial Guide </a><br> 
                                    <span class="ccavenue_bluezeal_link">
                                        <a href="https://www.bluezeal.in/support" target="_blank">Support</a>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="ccavenue-panel-2" style="display:none;">
                                    <div id="ccavenue_module_update_panel">
                                        <a> Avilable Updated Version:</a> 
                                        <br>Module version  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  : &nbsp; &nbsp; <span id="new_module_version"></span>
                                        <div>
                                            <br>Cms Version  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp; : &nbsp; &nbsp; <span id="new_cms_ver"></span>
                                            <br>Category Version  &nbsp;      : &nbsp; &nbsp; <span id="new_cat_ver"></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <a>
                                            <span class="red small about fontstyle" id="update_module_button" onclick="return update_newmodule();">Get Updated Module</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="ccavenue_file_download_panel">
                                    <a class="ccavenue_file_download_module" href="" id="Download_file">
                                    <button type="button">Download!</button>
                                    </a>
                                </div> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                ]]>
            </comment>
            <field id="active" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                <label>Enabled</label>
                <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
            </field>
            <field id="title" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Title</label>
            </field>
                <field id="allow_multiple_currency" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="3" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Allow Multiple Currency</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
            </field>
                <field id="new_order_status" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="4" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>New order status</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Sales\Model\Config\Source\Order\Status</source_model>
            </field>
                <field id="payment_success_order_status" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="5" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Payment Success order status</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Sales\Model\Config\Source\Order\Status</source_model>
            </field>
                <field id="allowed_currencies" translate="label" type="multiselect" sortOrder="6" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Allowed Currencies</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Ccavenuepay\Model\Adminhtml\Source\Currency</source_model>
            </field>
                <field id="payment_conformation_mail" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="7" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Payment Confirmation Mail</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
            </field>
                <field id="order_conformation_mail_before_payment" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="8" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Order Confirmation Mail Before Payment</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
            </field>
                <field id="merchant_id" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="11" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                <label>Merchant Id</label>
            </field>
                <field id="encryption_key" translate="label" type="password" sortOrder="9" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Encryption Key</label>
            </field>
                <field id="access_code" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Access Code</label>
            </field>
                <field id="minimum_order_total" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="16" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Minimum Order Total</label>
            </field>
                <field id="maximum_order_total" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="17" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Maximum Order Total</label>
            </field>

           <!-- <field id="merchant_gateway_key" translate="label" type="obscure" sortOrder="12" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                <label>Merchant Gateway Key</label>
                <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Encrypted</backend_model>
            </field> -->


            <field id="debug" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="15" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                <label>Debug</label>
                <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
            </field>
            <field id="payment_action" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="13" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                <label>Payment Action</label>
                <source_model>Magento\Ccavenuepay\Model\Adminhtml\Source\PaymentAction</source_model>
            </field>
            <field id="allowspecific" translate="label" type="allowspecific" sortOrder="14" showInDefault="1"
                   showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                <label>Payment From Applicable Countries</label>
                <source_model>Magento\Payment\Model\Config\Source\Allspecificcountries</source_model>
            </field>
            <field id="specificcountry" translate="label" type="multiselect" sortOrder="15" showInDefault="1"
                   showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                <label>Payment From Specific Countries</label>
                <source_model>Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country</source_model>
            </field>
            <field id="sort_order" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="19" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1"
                   showInStore="0">
                <label>Sort Order</label>
                <frontend_class>validate-number</frontend_class>
            </field>
        </group>
    </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Comment: Can you post your system.xml of your payment gateway?

Comment: @SukumarGoraiI have added system.xml. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your admin panel

Go to `Store->configuration->Sales->Payment Method->Ccavenuepay`

and set `Minimum Order Total` to `1` or `0.1`

Comment: yes. But this is not working in my case. When I am applying coupon my grand total becomes 0, in that case, I want to hide/disabled PAYMENT METHOD (CCAVENUEPAY). When I am trying to do it by you provided way its not working. Is there any other solution?